# Customize progress bar on JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I use very simple [progress bar with bootstarp](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/progressbar).

But I would like to create custom progress bar like this:
[image]

But I don't know how to create such progress bar. Maybe ready-to-use JS library exists or something else, for creating progress bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

- Use your meme image so that the face is transparent inside and white outside (or use your background color)
- Use a colored div (blue for example) which has the same size of your meme image, and put it hidden under your meme image
- On progress, slide the image to the top (using javascript) behind your meme (using z-index)
- You obtain your effect

Comment: Very interesting, you have give me please simple example